# Composition With StructureMap

Tags: c#, structuremap

Looking at a post by Karl Seguin where he show show designing for testability leads to a better design, in this case, [composition over inheritance](http://openmymind.net/2010/8/19/Design-Through-Testability-An-Example).

In the example, his `CachedEmployeeLookup` has a dependency on an `EmployeeLookup`, which both implement the same interface, `IEmployeeLookup`

How you would configure this in StructureMap so that the default class used by the program is `CachedEmployeeLookup` whilst `CachedEmployeeLookup` gets an `EmployeeLookup` injected to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like this would work:

```
For<IEmployeeLookup>().Add<EmployeeLookup>().
   Named("employeeLookup");

For<IEmployeeLookup>().Use<CachedEmployeeLookup>()
  .Ctor<IEmployeeLookup>().Is(
     d => d.TheInstanceNamed("employeeLookup"));
```

Comment: Oops! Had the wrong default object. Changed default to be correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `EnrichWith` when setting up the type mappings, e.g.

```
ObjectFactory.Initialize(i =>
{
    i.For<IDecorator>().Use<Inner>().EnrichWith(d => new Decorator(d));
});
```

[This page](http://structuremap.github.com/structuremap/Interception.htm) has some examples of interception in StructureMap